# How to calculate (x,y) position of number in square

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry

I am looking for a way to determine the X & Y position of a number to draw following square:

```
1   2   5   10  17
3   4   6   11
7   8   9   12
13  14  15  16
```

What kind of algorithm / formula can I use ?

I have tried rounding the square root of the number to determine the X position.

To be clear, here is what I want to achieve, numbers with their corresponding X and Y position:

```
#  X  Y
1: 1  1
2: 2  1
3: 1  2
4: 2  2
5: 3  1
6: 3  2
```

Comment: My intuition tells me that there is likely no simple formula for this, but rather an algorithm with potentially an auxiliary variable. This is because in some cases the numbers are growing downwards, and sometimes growing to the right. Maybe there will be an if-statement etc ...

Comment: What have you tried so far? How would you go about solving this problem? Is that just an exercise?

Comment: I did some attempts with square root of the number to determine the X position and a combination with modulo operation to determine Y. It's not just an exercise, I need to know where to place an element given its index from a programming standpoint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the pattern in your table:

```
 1 | 2 | 5 |10 |17
-------|   |   |
 3   4 | 6 |11 |
-----------|   |
 7   8   9 |12 |
---------------|
13  14  15  16 |
```

The algorithm of filling the table is as follows:

start with a 1×1 square with a single `1` in it:

```
|1|
```

add a column along the right side of the defined area, filling it with consecutive natural numbers (it will be 1-item column with a single `2` in it):

```
1|2|
```

add a row along the bottom side of the defined area, filling it with consecutive natural numbers (it will be 2-items row with numbers `3` & `4`):

```
 1 2
-----
|3 4|
```

add a column along the right side of the defined area, filling it with consecutive natural numbers (it will be 2-item column with numbers `5` & `6`):

```
1 2|5|  
3 4|6|
```

add a row along the bottom side of the defined area, filling it with consecutive natural numbers (it will be 3-items row with numbers `7` through `9`):

```
  1 2 5
  3 4 6
 -------
 |7 8 9|
```

and so on, expand the area by a column and by a row, a column and a row, ...

So, after completing a $k\times k$ square you make a new one of size $(k+1)\times (k+1)$, by placing numbers $k^2+1\dots k^2+k$ in a column $(k+1)$, rows $1$ through $k$, and then numbers $k^2+k+1\dots k^2+2k+1 = (k+1)^2$ in row $(k+1)$, columns $1 \dots k+1$.

Recovering coordinates for a given $n$ is quite easy now: find the largest square $k^2$ less than your number:
$$k^2\lt n$$
and test if $n$ is in the $(k+1)$-st column or $(k+1)$-st row.

If $k^2 \lt n \le k^2+k$, then $row=n-k^2, col=k+1$.
If $k^2+k \lt n \le (k+1)^2$, then $row=k+1, col=n-(k^2+k)$.

Comment: This one actually makes most sense thanks to explaining the thought process to arrive at the algorithm, thank you very much

Comment: k=⌊√n⌋ here, right? and ⌊⌋  means rounding to the nearest integer?

Comment: @RobSeg Nope.  The floor function returns its argument if integer, so for $n$ being a perfect square  $n=c^2$ the expression would yield $\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor =c$ which makes, of course, $c^2=n$ while I demand $k^2 \lt n$. This implies $k^2 \le n-1$ hence $k=\lfloor \sqrt {n \color{red}{-1}}\rfloor$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we want to find the $(x,y)$ position of $n = k^2 + r$ with $0 \le r < (k + 1)^2$. That is $k := \lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor$. So the $y$ position grows by $1$ every step, until it reaches $k^2 + k + 1$. 
Thus: $$y = \min\{n - k^2, k + 1\}$$
Now, $x$ has the value $k + 1$ from $k^2 + 1$ to $k^2 + k$, and grows by $1$ every step after that. Thus:
$$x = \begin{cases} k + 1 & , n \le k^2 + k\\ 
n - (k^2 + k) & ,  n \gt k^2 + k \end{cases}$$

Comment: @Arthur Thanks, edited for clarity.

Comment: Thank you! But I don't understand the X part sorry, please bear in mind I'm totally non-mathematic. I don't know how to read this properly. Is it possible to rewrite the X part into something more like a single expression, like the Y calculation?

Comment: @RobSeg Technically, yes, it's probably possible. It will likely be completely unreadable, though. If it's the $\{$ notation you're having trouble with, that's just a way to write a value with different definitions depending on cases. The case is after the comma, and the corresponding value is before the comma. So for any $n$ where $n\leq k^2+k$, then $x = k+1$, for instance.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation

Comment: @RobSeg One way to do it would be $x = (n- k^2 - k) \cdot \lfloor n/(k^2 + k + 1)\rfloor + (k + 1) \cdot (\lfloor -n/(k^2 + k )\rfloor + 2)$. This way, the left side of the expression is multiplied by $0$ when $n \lt k^2 + k +1$ and by $1$ otherwise. The right side is multiplied by $(-1 + 2)$ when $n \lt k^2 + k +1$ and by $(-2 + 2)$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Given your number $n$, let $n_0$ and $n_1$ be consecutive perfect squares such that $n_0<n\leq n_1$ (in symbols, using the ceiling function, they may be written as $n_0 = (\lceil \sqrt{n}\rceil - 1)^2$ and $n_1 = \lceil \sqrt n\rceil^2$).

Now, compare $n-n_0$ to $n_1-n$ (in other words, check whether $n$ is closest to $n_0$ or to $n_1$). (As a side note, they can never be equal, which is a neat little exercise on its own.) We get two cases:

- $n-n_0<n_1-n$: Then $x = \sqrt{n_1}$ and $y = n-n_0$
- $n-n_0>n_1-n$: Then $x = n - \frac{n_0+n_1-1}{2}$ and $y = \sqrt{n_1}$

You may be able to bake this into a single formula, but it will be large and practically unreadable. At any rate, since this is for programming, a simple if-test will probably suffice, and might be faster too (at least if $n$ is going to get large so that the processor can exploit branch predictions).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm (written for Matlab) that works:

```
n = 5;

x = zeros(n*n,1);
y = zeros(n*n,1);

x(1) = 1;  % set the first 3 points
y(1) = 1;
x(2) = 2;
y(2) = 1;
x(3) = 1;
y(3) = 2;

for i = 4:n*n
    if (x(i-1) == y(i-1))       % jump all the way down (and 1 to the right)
        x(i) = x(i-1)+1;    
        y(i) = 1;
    elseif (x(i-1) == y(i-1)+1) % jump all the way to the left (and 1 up)
        x(i) = 1;           
        y(i) = y(i-1)+1;
    elseif (x(i-1) > y(i-1))    % move 1 up
        x(i) = x(i-1);
        y(i) = y(i-1)+1;
    else        
        x(i) = x(i-1)+1;        % move 1 to the right
        y(i) = y(i-1);
    end
end
```

If at the end you call `plot(x,y)` you get the following figure:

[image]